# Clojure recursive function gives null-pointer exception

Tags: recursion, clojure

When defining a simple recursive function with fn, as follows,

```
((fn myfunc [x] (if (zero? x) (println "STOP") ((println x) (myfunc (dec x))))) 6)
```

it prints 6,5,4,3,2,1,STOP and then I get a null-pointer exception in the REPL. Is this not legal syntax?

I know I can define functions with def, and there (should) not be any issue with recursion there. I am simply curious about the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lisps, using parenthesis means "treat the first argument in the list as a function, and invoke it with the rest of the arguments in the list".

In your case, you have `((println x) (myfunc (dec x)))`. The first `(println x)` gets invoked, returning a `nil`, to get `(nil (myfunc (dec x)))`, and then `nil` is attempting to get invoked as a function with the result of the recursion. This is what causing the NPE exception to be thrown.

If you want to have multiple expressions in clojure, you could use the `do` macro, so the same code would look like: `(do (println x) (myfunc (dec x)))`.

`do` essentially runs all the expressions for their side-effects, returning only the result of the last expression.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, so the error were at a completely different place than i expected.